# plotting ordinal regression results

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, regression, visualization

I'm trying to visualize the estimated slopes for the interaction between `response:temp` of an ordinal regression using the `ordinal` package

```
library(ordinal)
wine2 <- wine
wine2$rating[wine2$rating==5] <- 1
wine2$rating <- ordered(wine2$rating)

fm1 <- clm(rating ~ response*temp, data=wine2)
summary(fm1)

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
response           0.14478    0.02965   4.883 1.04e-06 ***
tempwarm           6.89043    1.78282   3.865 0.000111 ***
response:tempwarm -0.15651    0.03874  -4.040 5.34e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2    3.389      1.022   3.317
2|3    5.610      1.171   4.789
3|4    7.830      1.294   6.053
```

I can extract the slope estimates for the `response:tempcold` (0.14) and `response:tempwarm` (-0.01), but how can I visualize these slopes with the ordinal outcome variable on the y axis?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this with `ggeffects`?

```
library(sjmisc)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggeffects)

sapply(wine2, class)
# $response
# [1] "numeric"

# $temp
#[1] "factor"

# $rating
# [1] "ordered" "factor" 

unique(wine2$rating)
# [1] 2 3 4 1
# Levels: 1 < 2 < 3 < 4

unique(wine2$temp)
# [1] cold warm
# Levels: cold warm

unique(wine2$response)
# [1] 36 48 47 67 77 60 83 90 17 22 14 50 30 51 70 42 23 80 81 73 62 46 27 32 57 37 84 58 26 45 61 41 55 54 88 13 19 31 29 43
# [41] 49 25 39 40 12 28 38 72 65

# select all levels from continuous variable response
pred <- ggpredict(fm1, terms = c("response[all]", "temp"))
plot(pred) + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `marginaleffects` package](https://marginaleffects.com) to plot either predictions or slopes (disclaimer: I am the maintainer).

I’m not 100% sure what plot you have in mind, but here are a couple of examples. They should be pretty easy to adapt to your needs.

```r
library(ordinal)
library(marginaleffects)
library(ggplot2)
wine2 <- wine
wine2$rating[wine2$rating==5] <- 1
wine2$rating <- ordered(wine2$rating)

fm1 <- clm(rating ~ response*temp, data=wine2)

plot_predictions(fm1,
  type = "prob",
  condition = c("response", "group", "temp"))
```

[image]

```r
plot_slopes(fm1,
  type = "prob",
  variables = "temp",
  condition = c("response", "group")) +
  labs(fill = "Rating", color = "Rating") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Vincent, are you sure the confidence intervals for the probabilities are correct? They exceed the upper and lower bounds (100% and 0%). See plots from _ggeffects_ where everything is properly inside the bounds.

Comment: (looks like the [Stata issue](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/technical_stata.html))

Comment: @Daniel Exactly. `marginaleffects` use the delta method to calculate most derived predicted values, giving estimates and standard errors on the response scale. You can take the resulting data frame of predicted probabilities and their standard errors from `marginaleffects`, transform them to the linear-predictor scale, then transform them back. For ordinal regression however, the categorical probability is a difference between two adjacent cumulative probabilities. We can nevertheless apply the logit transformation using functions `d/p/qlogis()` for both cumulative and categorical probability.

Comment: Could you add details on when and why you need to add `"group"` to the `condition` argument? The help page only states "names of predictors to display" without specifying that "group" is sometimes also necessary.